# How to update an image using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update an image in my database using Laravel but unfortunately, the image is not updating. How can I resolve this issue?

**Controller**

```php
public function updateaction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $category = $request->input('select_category');
    $project_name = $request->input('product_name');

    $image = $request->file('select_file');
    $new_name = mt_rand().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('projects'), $new_name);
    $updaterecord = DB::table('projects')->where(['products_id' => $id])->update([
        'project_name' => $project_name, 'category_id' => $category, 'image' => $image
    ]);

    if ($updaterecord) {
        return redirect('view_project');
    }

    return back();
}
```

**View**

```php
<form action="{{route('project.update', $project->products_id)}}" method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="group-form">
        <select class="form-control" name="select_category" required>
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{$category->id}}" @if($project->category_id) == $category->id)  @endif>
                {{$category->category_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="group-form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$project->project_name}}"
               placeholder="Update Product Name" name="product_name" required>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="group-form">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" value="{{asset('/public/projects/'.$projects->image)}}"
               name="select_file">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="group-form">
        <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary form-control" value="UPDATE" name="Update">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Route**

```php
Route::post('project_update/{id}/update', 'AdminController@updateaction')
    ->name('project.update');
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOUR MODEL IS NOT UPDATING THE 'image' ATTRIBUTE BECAUSE **YOU ASSIGN TO IT AN OBJECT (`$image`) INSTEAD OF A STRING** (`$new_name`).

TRY TO REPLACE `$image` VARIABLE INSIDE THE `UPDATE()` METHOD WITH `$new_name`.

SEE :

```
public function updateaction(Request $request,$id)
    {     
        $category=$request->input('select_category');
        $project_name=$request->input('product_name'); 

        $image = $request->file('select_file');
        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path('projects'), $new_name);            
        $updaterecord=DB::table('projects')->where(['products_id'=> $id])
        ->update(['project_name'=>$project_name,'category_id'=>$category,'image'=>$new_name]);

        if($updaterecord){
            return redirect('view_project');
        }
    }
```

Comment: The caps lock key was stuck

Answer (score 2):

You try to save UploadedFile object to database. I think, you need to save a string with file name, for example, $new_name instead of $image.